# Dialectics vs Overdetermination

Tags: dialectic

Is overdetermination a more broad form of dialectics? Something of a pluralistic "antithesis" maybe? If this is not correct, what is the distinction?

Comment: See [Overdetermination in Althusser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermination#Althusser_and_structuralist_Marxism)

Comment: I've come across this, but I still don't understand the relation/distinction between the two.

Comment: In the example:  It moves it further away from the “whole” of capitalism, which is rotten. It is to far from true undifferentiated (whole) being which in capitalism is false. The event itself takes on too much importance.  Background http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/97865/2/determination%20is%20negation%20paper%20final.pdf

Comment: The whole is untrue (in capitalism) https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/adornos-practical-philosophy/whole-is-untrue/E9EA71F20102E27E3F7D305317B67026

Comment: I can only assume Freud had read Spinoza (and maybe Hegel), or as a great thinker he stumbled on this himself.

Comment: Freud: https://musictheorythesis.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/over-determination-from-on-dreams/

Comment: In order to arrive a a singular thing, determination, which exists in a whole set of dream thoughts, you have to kill it, or negate it.  I would say all singulars are overdetermined in this way  You are taking it out of the context of a whole. There is a paper up there on determination as negation. Spinoza and Hegel. And books on Spinoza and Hegel that I have not read.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, especially the further reading. Could you give me an example of whole/undifferentiated concepts and singular/differentiated concept? Within any topic.

Comment: Read the white rose paper above and pay very close attention to Spinoza. Actuality is going to be the whole.  Any singular thing taking out of the whole, say a butterfly taken from nature and pinned to a board, to be determined as that singular, to be A=A, we are negating it, essentially killing it. In reality (the whole) there is no A=A “thing”. So to, for instance, under Freud to arrive at one dream, it is such a radical simplification from all the dream thoughts in the entire whole of determinations.

Comment: Hegel or Spinoza, Pierre Macherey. But don’t read just one book or paper on the subject.